# can't create TabPanels in TabContainer in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, tabs, tabpanel, tabcontainer

I have TabContainer, which I'm adding dynamically TabPanels to.

The problem is that if I do not have at least one Hard coded TabPanel, I can't see all TabPanels.

This is the TabContainer:

```
         <cc1:TabContainer ID="TabContainer1" runat="server"  AutoPostBack="true" >
  <cc1:TabPanel ID="TabPanel0" runat="server" HeaderText="TabPanel1" >
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><br />
                    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />
                </ContentTemplate>
  </cc1:TabPanel>
    </cc1:TabContainer>
```

and this is the TabPanels adding:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < WorkOrderTabs.AllTexts.Count; i++)
    {

        TabPanel tab = new TabPanel();
        AttributesAndLabels AAL = new AttributesAndLabels(1, i);
        tab.ID = "tabPanel" + (i+1);
        tab.HeaderText = AAL.AllTexts[0];
        tab.Visible = true;                
        Control pdage = Page.LoadControl(FH.SubUserControlersWorkOrderPath + WorkOrderTabs.AllTexts[i]);                
        TabContainer1.Tabs.Add(tab);
        TabContainer1.Tabs[i+1].Controls.Add(pdage);

    }
```

If I delete the Hard Coded TabPanel all dynamic TabPanels will become unvisiable.

really Strange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that none of the TabPanels was active.

When you create TabPanels dynamically you need to put one of them as Active in the TabContainer.